# How to get the results which has all the strings specified in the search query

Tags: lucene

I am a beginner in Lucene. I am writing a search engine to search our code base for certain key words. I have a requirement for which I need your help. Say I am searching for a word "Apple computers", I would like Lucene to throw only the lines which have case insesitive "apple computers". But what I see is I see lines having Apple computers, lines having only apple and lines having only computers. How do I filter it to get only the lines having apple and computer.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for all the help. I used the phrase query and used proper slop value. The result just was the one I was looking for. The Boolean query too worked. The Book "Lucene in Action" answered all my queries. I recommend this book strongly to all who wants to learn Lucene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you query Lucene? Basically what you are asking about is covered by building a query using [BooleanClause.Occur.MUST](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanClause.Occur.html). 
Exactly how to do this is dependent on your query construction: For the default query parser you should use something like

> +Apple +computers

While if you are building queries programmatically you should use MUST for every term.

Answer (score 0):

As Yuval suggested, it's important to know how do you use Lucene.
If you use it through lucene-java and need exact phrase results (docs that contain only "apple computers" together) you can use [PhraseQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/PhraseQuery.html).

[The example of how to compose it](http://www.coderanch.com/t/492463/open-source/Lucene-PhraseQuery).

Comment: Thanks for all the valuable inputs. I am following the same approach. But another requirement is that I need to highlight the strings in the results I get. But when i use the TermFreqVector,TermPositionVector the offsets I get still points to lines which has only apple and sole lines which have computers only. I am storing the entire content of the file as one document against the field name "contents". I think my approach is wrong and I need to idex line by line. Is this correct. Or which is a better approach to highlight the search results. Any help much app